# Firebase ios: get list of users by IDs

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Situation: I have a database with users, users can have friends and friends are linked to current user model as userID. So when I'm loading user data I'm receiving also a list of firebase IDs of his friends.

Question: Is there any way to receive firebase snapshot with all this users at once? Haven't found any suitable solution - .child() is linking directly with one object, queryOrderedByChild() and queryOrderedByValue() doesn't seem to make such requests.

Will be grateful for any advice.

Edit: Database structure:

```
{
    "Users": {
        "user_id_first" : {
            "user_info" : {
                "name": "name",
                "age": "age"
            },
            "friends": {}
        },

        "user_id_second" : {
            "user_info" : {
                "name": "name",
                "age": "age"
            },
            "friends": {}
        },

        "user_id_third" : {
            "user_info" : {
                "name": "name",
                "age": "age"
            },
            "friends": {
                "user_id_first" : true,
                "user_id_second" : true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are list of friend IDs, which are actually IDs of firebase users. All I need is to retrieve information for these users in one firebase snapshot (i.e. use one reference) without creating new reference for each friend like

```
myDBRef.child("Users").child("friend_id")
```

Comment: Please show the minimal JSON (as text, no screenshot) that shows what you've already done and where you are stuck. Without that, it''ll be difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop to access all the friendsId :-

```
 let parentRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users")
   parentRef.child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("friends").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(snapshot) in

  if snapshot.exists(){

    if let friendsDictionary = snapshot.Value as! NSMutableDictionary{

              for each in friendsDictionary as! [String : AnyObject]{

                     let friendsId = each.0 as! String

                     parentRef.child(friendId).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(friendDictionary)

                     if let friendsInfo = friendDictionary.Value as! NSMutableDictionary{
                          //retrieve the info
                }
             })
           }
       }
    }
 })
```

Comment: I was thinking of the same approach but is this a good way to solve it? I mean how about performance and so on?